# Chrome and Safari suddenly display my webfont <h1> in completely the wrong place

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, safari

I've searched the forums but the only answers I'm getting cover issues about the font looking bold or having jaggedy edges.

My h1 @font-face font is displaying at the BOTTOM of my page in Chrome and Safari as of today. I have no idea why. It was fine before.

A good page example to look at is https://www.beatnikbreaks.com/about-us/ - have a look in Chrome and then in Firefox. Firefox displays it at the top as it should be.

Chrome loads it at the top first, then it suddenly jumps to the bottom.

My CSS for the font is:

```
#pagecontent h1{

margin-top: 0px;
color: #b9b9b9;
font-family: 'lucky_typewriterregular',Times,serif;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 44px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin-left: 0px;
float: left;
text-align: left;
width: 1000px;
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="pagecontent">

<p></p>
<h1>About Beatnik Breaks</h1>

<h2>About Beatnik Breaks - Large luxury holiday short term rental in Brighton, ideal for holiday letting and stag &amp; hen party accommodation</h2>

<p></p>

<p>We're a little bit shy... some details about us will follow. Or if there's something specific you want to know, then give us a call or <a class="highlight" href="contact-us">email us</a>...
</p>

<p></p>


</div>
```

I did update my Wordpress very recently, but I can't see why this would have suddenly done this.

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think can be a problem realted to float, try to add float at pagecontent (the actual container of h1)

```
#pagecontent{
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me Cesare. I actually fixed this now. Some of the pages were displaying correctly so I analysed the differences between the OK page and the broken page. The culprit was 3rd party code from Facebook. It was a little 'like this page' button - the code for which was suddenly not rendering my layout correctly. It had an affect on the whole layout. I learned a lesson there - beware of 3rd party code...